# Keras Metric Issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using the latest version of tensorflow ( 1.13 ) . I am using Keras API in order to train LSTM network.

I cant not train with `tf.keras.metrics.Precision()` and `tf.keras.metrics.Recall()`

It is compiling. But during training, I am getting the following error

> InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0]
>   [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:x (dense_3/BiasAdd:0) = ]
>   [[[2.72658144e-06 1.17555362e-06 1.96436554e-06...]]...] [y
>   (metrics_3/precision_1/Cast/x:0) = ] [0]   [[{{node
>   metrics_3/precision_1/assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]

The model is very simple as follows

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM (120,activation = "tanh", input_shape=(timesteps,dim), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(120, activation = "tanh", return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(120, activation = "tanh", return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(120, activation = "tanh", return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(120, activation = "tanh", return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(120, activation = "tanh", return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(dim))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse",  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])

history = model.fit(data,data, 
                    epochs=100,
                    batch_size=10,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    shuffle=True,
                    callbacks=[ch]).history
```

Is it a Bug or I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`Precision` and `recall` are metrics to measure classification performance. Since you are using `mse` and linear activation in the last layer you are rather doing a regression.

If you want to classify, make sure that you create outputs in the range of `[0,1]`. This can be obtained by using `sigmoid` or `softmax` activation in the last layer, depending on your problem. (binary or n-class classification)

Further make sure that your output shape is correct since you got `return_sequences=True` in your last LSTM layer, which may not be what you want.

**EDIT**: Due to your `model.fit` call I can see now, that you are trying to autoencode your data. Therefore `precision` as a metric doesn't make sense here.

Comment: I have applied what you have suggested. But I am getting the following error
`InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [10,9] vs. [10,50,9]
  [[{{node loss/dense_loss/sub}}]]`

Comment: What I am doing is a classification problem. anomaly detection. Trying to create a autoencoder

Comment: You are contradicting yourself kinda. When you want to classify, you hand in some data and return a class label. When you want to autoencode, you hand in some data, add a bottleneck to your network and try to reconstruct the input given the compressed representation. Since you mentioned it now, I can see that you are trying to autoencode your data. Therefore `precision` as a metric doesn't make sense actually.

Comment: I wanted to use F1, But for that i need precision  and recall.

Comment: else what would you suggest ? The autoencoder is for anomaly detection

Comment: `F1` score measures classification performance as well. When you are trying to detect anomalies, you are typically using the learned compressed representations of your inputs and look for outliers or clusters unsupervised inside these representations.

Comment: Thank you so much. This information was really helpful

Comment: I am working with multiple signals .But when you have univarient data, meaning only one class, How can I create that bottelneck ?

Comment: There are several tutorials for these tasks like [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-autoencoders/).